# Product Sorting with layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9

I have products listed in a catagory and able to sort with layered navigation.  However, I wanted to add a table prior to the products to better describe each one.  See link below to see:
http://www.oxidationtech.com/products/ozone-generators.html

What I want, is when a selection from the layered navigation on the left is selected, the table should disappear as it is no longer necessary.  I would prefer after a selection to narrow-down from layered navigation is selected that only the selected products in that range appear.

Any ideas how I can have both?  Table on landing page + usable layered navigaion?

Answer (score 0):

In your category view template file, or wherever else you are displaying the table, you can do this

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
    ... DISPLAY TABLE ...
<?php endif; ?>
```

I didn't test whether the filters also include the page number, so you may want to test that out.